# How to restrict merging specific branch into other branches in Gitlab?

Tags: python, git, merge, gitlab

Is there a way to restrict merging **from** a specific branch into other branches? Allow me to explain:

I have a 'testing' branch and a 'master' branch in Gitlab. The team creates feature branches, merges them **into** 'testing' for approval and then merge the feature branch **into** 'master' once approved.

Sometimes, it can take months to get approval of some features, and therefore code is sat in the 'testing' branch for a while. Meanwhile, another feature branch may try to merge into 'testing' and conflicts will arise. This is expected, however, we are only human, and occasionally someone may accidentally merge 'testing' into their feature branch when handling the conflict, which is obviously wrong. Instead, we should switch to 'testing' and merge our feature branch into 'testing' thus managing the conflict within the testing branch.

Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To begin, be sure your needs is very normal and traditional.
The answer is ... Yes.

### How to prevent merging from a branch to another, setting up a server Git Hook

These are some useful links:

- [Git Hook explanations](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in Official Git Book
- [GitLab server-side Hook explanations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html)
- [An example](https://gist.github.com/mwise/69ec35b646b52d98050d) with a Git Hook written in Ruby to prevent merging 'staging' branch to 'master' one

To help you (and for fun ^^), I wrote a dedicated hook in Python to reach your specific needs (you just need to adapt FORBIDDEN_SOURCE_BRANCH and FORBIDDEN_IF_NOT_DEST_BRANCH if you want to work with some other branches).

```
#!/bin/python
##
## Author: Bertrand Benoit <mailto:contact@bertrand-benoit.net>
## Description: Git Hook (server-side) allowing to prevent merge from some branches to anothers
## Version: 0.9

import sys, subprocess, re

FORBIDDEN_SOURCE_BRANCH='testing'
FORBIDDEN_IF_NOT_DEST_BRANCH='master'

# Considers only merge commit.
if not (len(sys.argv) >=2 and sys.argv[2] == 'merge'):
    sys.exit(0)

# Defines which is the source branch.
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    mergeMessage=f.readline()
mergeBranchExtract=re.compile("Merge branch '([^']*)'.*$").search(mergeMessage)
if not mergeBranchExtract:
    print('Unable to extract branch to merge from message: ', mergeMessage)
    sys.exit(0) # Ensures normal merge as failback

# Checks if the merge (source) branch is one of those to check.
mergeBranch=mergeBranchExtract.group(1)
if mergeBranch != FORBIDDEN_SOURCE_BRANCH:
  sys.exit(0) # It is NOT the forbidden source branch, so keeps on normal merge

# Defines which is the current branch.
currentBranchFullName=subprocess.check_output(['git', 'symbolic-ref', 'HEAD'])
currentBranchExtract=re.compile("^.*/([^/]*)\n$").search(currentBranchFullName)
if not currentBranchExtract:
  print('Unable to extract current branch from: ', currentBranchFullName)
  sys.exit(1) # Ensures normal merge as failback

# Checks if the current (destination) branch is one of those to check.
currentBranch=currentBranchExtract.group(1)
if currentBranch != FORBIDDEN_IF_NOT_DEST_BRANCH:
  print("FORBIDDEN: Merging from '" + mergeBranch + "' to '" + currentBranch + "' is NOT allowed. Contact your administrator. Now, you should use git merge --abort and keep on your work.")
  sys.exit(1) # This is exactly the situation which is forbidden

# All is OK, so keeps on normal merge
sys.exit(0)
```

To share all this work, I created a new [Gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/bertrand-benoit/pyGitHook), in which I'll add further hooks when needed :)

### For information, you can also setup protected branches to keep them safe from some users

This is the [complete documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/) about that.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: But I've had the impression that OP wanted a way to prevent merging *from* a specific branch rather than *to* a specific branch...

Comment: @RomainValeri That's correct, I want to prevent merging FROM a specific branch.

Comment: I updated my answer consequently to reach your needs.

Comment: To help you (and for fun ^^), I wrote a dedicated hook in Python to reach your specific needs. I updated my answer consequently.

Answer (score 3):

So, what you want your pre-receive hook to reject is any branch push that incorporates the current `testing` tip if there's something there, unless the push is to `testing` itself, or to `master`.  It's almost as easy to do that as to say it:

```
testtip=`git rev-parse testing`
[[ `git merge-base testing master` = $testtip ]] && exit 0    # okay if testing's merged

while read old new ref; do
        [[ $ref = refs/heads/* ]] || continue      # only care about branches
        [[ $new = *[^0]* ]] || continue            # not checking branch deletions
        [[ $ref = */master ]] && continue          # not checking pushes to master
        [[ $ref = */testing ]] && continue         # nor testing


        range=$new; [[ $old = *[^0]* ]] && range=$old..$new

        [[ `git rev-list --first-parent $range` != *$testtip* ]] \
        && [[ `git rev-list $range` = *$testtip* ]] \
        && {
                echo push to $ref merges from unmerged testing commits, rejecting push
                exit 1
        }
done
```

edit: whoops, it was rejecting anything based on testing, not just anything that merged it. fixed.

Comment: Could you explain where your code is suppose to be run please? I do not recognize the language nor the usage of it sorry. Looks like bash?

Comment: @JulienRousé That's a pre-receive hook, yes, it's bash. say `git help hooks`.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be supported officially with See [GitLab 16.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/10/22/gitlab-16-5-released/#create-rules-to-set-target-branches-for-merge-requests) (October 2023), but only for premium/ultimate GitLab.

> ### Create rules to set target branches for merge requests
>
> Some projects use multiple long-term branches for development, like `develop` and `qa`. In these projects, you might want to keep `main` as the default branch since it represents the production state of the project.
> However, development work expects merge requests to target `develop` or `qa`. >
> Target branch rules help ensure merge requests target the appropriate branch for your project and development workflow.
>
> When you create a merge request, the rule checks the name of the branch. If the branch name matches the rule, the merge request pre-selects the branch you specified in the rule as the target. If the branch name does not match, the merge request targets the default branch of the project.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_5/create-target-branch-rules.png -- Create rules to set target branches for merge requests]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/#configure-rules-for-target-branches) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17909).